# How to access .style on namespaced elements in XHTML

Tags: javascript, css, dom

In a browser that is displaying an XHTML document with namespaced elements, how can I use JavaScript to access the `.style` properties of an element outside the HTML namespace?

`document.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tagName)` returns a collection of objects but the objects don’t have a `CSSStyleDeclaration` style property (at least not in Chrome or Firefox).

You could say that is by design, that CSS is specific to HTML. But namespaced CSS styles the content just fine. So the style information is in there somewhere. How do I read and write it?

I want to know, for example, which elements are being rendered as blocks and which inline.

(Edit to add example:)

To see this, go to [www.johnmccaskey.com/style.xhtml](http://www.johnmccaskey.com/style.xhtml). The blue part is in HTML namespace, the red part in `http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0` namespace. CSS styled them both just fine. In, say, Chrome’s console, enter `document.getElementsByTagName("box")`. You’ll see the two `<box>` objects. The HTML one has a `.style` property, the TEI one does not.

Comment: `getElementsByTagNameNS` returns a collection of elements, so the result wouldn't have any `style` property. If you do `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tagName)[0].style` does that give you something?

Comment: Oops, I did mean the objects in the collection lack `.style`. I’ve edited the question.

Comment: Okay. If you could include some code which causes this behavior, it would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I added a link to a site showing the behavior.

Comment: So, we require any code to be in the question itself, not on a third-party site. This question will be less helpful to others if that page goes missing someday.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that here? I don’t know if I can use fiddle since, because this is specific to XHTML, how the web server is configured might be important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.style` property is a reflection of the content attribute on the HTML element, e.g. `<div style="color:green">`, not a reflection of its computed styles obtained from the cascade.

To get the computed values, use window.getComputedStyle().

To see it in action, add this script to your XHTML, just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>
var boxes = document.body.children;
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(boxes[0], null).getPropertyValue("color"));
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(boxes[1], null).getPropertyValue("color"));
</script>
```

And inspect the console output.

To tell whether an element is inline or block or some other display value, use `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("display")`

Comment: How do I set such values?

Comment: Through the cascade. Create or modify a stylesheet object.

Comment: Nothing direct, eh? :-(

Comment: That's because it's an instance of `Element`, not `HTMLElement`. Only html and svg elements implement the inline style interface. https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#elementcssinlinestyle